# In Finding Broken links script ( using Selenium Robot Framework) -In Get Request URL's are going twice by appending

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am not sure what's wrong in the below Get Request, when i run the script in Get Request link appended.

**Issue :**
GET Request : url=http://127.0.0.1:5000//http://127.0.0.1:5000/index.html

Please see the below code and the Report screenshot.

I am stuck here! Really appreciate  for the help.

```html
${url3}   http://127.0.0.1:5000/
${BROWSER}  chrome
*** Test Cases ***
 
BrokenLinksTest-ForPracticeSelenium-2ndPage
    Open Browser    ${url3}  ${BROWSER}
    Maximize Browser Window
    VerifyAllLinksOn2ndPage
    Close Browser
*** Keywords ***

VerifyAllLinksOn2ndPage
    Comment    Count Number Of Links on the Page
    ${AllLinksCount}=    get element count     xpath://a
    Comment    Log links count
    Log    ${AllLinksCount}
    Comment    Create a list to store link texts
    @{LinkItems}    Create List
    Comment    Loop through all links and store links value that has length more than 1 character
    : FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE    1    ${AllLinksCount}-1
    \    Log    ${INDEX}

    \    ${link_text}=    Get Text    xpath=(//a)[${INDEX}]   #<-- for what ? -->
    \    ${href}=    Get Element Attribute    xpath=(//a)[${INDEX}]     href

    \    Log    ${link_text}
    \    log to console  ("The link text is "${link_text}" & href is "${href}" ${INDEX})

    \    ${linklength}    Get Length    ${link_text}  #<-- you are checking text not href ? -->
    \    Run Keyword If    ${linklength}>1    Append To List    ${LinkItems}    ${href}
    Log Many    ${LinkItems}
    Remove Values From List  ${LinkItems}  javascript:void(0)     #<-- don't forget checking content on list -->
    ${linkitems_length}    Get Length    ${LinkItems}
    Log Many    ${LinkItems}
    @{errors_msg}    Create List
    Create Session    secondpage   http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    :FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE   ${linkitems_length}
    \    Log Many     ${LinkItems[${INDEX}]}
    \    ${ret}    get request   secondpage     ${LinkItems[${INDEX}]}
    \    log to console      ${ret}
    \    log       ${ret}
    \    ${code}    Run Keyword And Return Status    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${ret.status_code}    200
    #\   log to console  "Gonna link"  ${LinkItems[${INDEX}]}
   # \   click link      ${LinkItems[${INDEX}]}
   #\   Capture Page Screenshot
   #\   Click Link         link=${LinkItems[${INDEX}]}
    \    Run Keyword Unless    ${code}    Append To List    ${errors_msg}    error :${LinkItems[${INDEX}]} | ${ret.status_code}
    ${check}    Run Keyword And Return Status    Lists Should Be Equal    ${errors_msg}    ${EMPTY}
    Run Keyword Unless    ${check}    Fail    Link \ assertion Failed with msg:\n@{errors_msg}
    Sleep  1
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the output of the first `Log Many    ${LinkItems}`?

Comment: @Pravelsaman .Please see the attached  2nd screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the "problem" is with these two lines:

```
Create Session    secondpage   http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

and:

```
${ret}    get request   secondpage     ${LinkItems[${INDEX}]}
```

As your screens show, your list of items (`@{LinkItems}`) already contains full url links, e.g.: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/index.html` but the `Create Session` keyword adds another `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` in front of each list item.

Think about it as BASE_URL set up by `Create Session` keyword and an endpoint, e.g. `/index.html`. `Create Session` and `Get Request` are used together, the former setting up BASE_URL, the latter the endpoint part of the URL. You can see the [documentation for the `Create Session` keyword](http://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-requests/doc/RequestsLibrary.html#Create%20Session), it explains its second parameter:

> `url` Base url of the server

To solve this, you'd need to store in `@{LinkItems}` only everything after last `/` (it seems so in your case), so for example only `/index.html` or `/shop.html`